# How to use inserts in a Liquibase JSON changelog?

Tags: java, json, postgresql, maven, liquibase

I'm just starting to use [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/index.html) (3.5.3) in a Java (1.8) project with Maven (3.3.9) and PostgreSQL (9.5.4). I'm not understanding why the second changeset of the following json changelog file is not working as expected.

```
{
  "databaseChangeLog": [
    {
      "preConditions": [
        {
          "dbms": { "type": "postgresql" },
          "runningAs": { "username": "postgres" }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "changeSet": {
        "id": "1",
        "author": "fernando.costa",
        "changes": [
          {
            "createTable": {
              "tableName": "contact",
              "columns": [
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "bigint",
                    "autoIncrement": true,
                    "constraints": {
                      "primaryKey": true,
                      "nullable": false
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "first_name",
                    "type": "varchar(100)",
                    "constraints": { "nullable": false }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "changeSet": {
        "id": "2",
        "author": "fernando.costa",
        "changes": [
          {
            "insert": {
              "tableName": "contact",
              "columns": [
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "first_name",
                    "value": "George"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

First changeset is fine, but the second one is not executed. It throws the following error:

> SEVERE 12/9/16 5:30 AM:liquibase: db.changelog.json: db.changelog.json::2::fernando.costa: Change Set db.changelog.json::2::fernando.costa failed.  Error: Error executing SQL INSERT INTO contact (first_name) VALUES (NULL): ERROR: null value in column "first_name" violates not-null constraint
>     Detail: Failing row contains (1, null).

What am I doing wrong? I have set `first_name` to `George`, but the generated SQL statement seems to be inserting NULL...

Thanks!

Comment: I've just posted this as an issue at jira https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2962?jql=status%20%3D%20Open%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC

Comment: did you try putting the insert inside the same changeset as the create table?